# Standing out in the era of big science

Tags: application, collaboration, physics, mega-collaborations

How do scientists who choose to work on big collaborative projects (e.g. LHC experiments, LIGO, etc.) differentiate themselves when time comes to apply for post doc/professor positions, considering their papers can have hundreds or more authors?

Comment: I might suggest changing the title of the question to something more akin to "How to stand out when working as a member of a large academic team?" to differentiate this question from a "how to do I stand out as the next Einstein?" question.  I very much like this question :)

Comment: Perhaps you could add value to yourself, the whole package, by getting involved in outreach.  Also, emphasize whatever special side talents you may have been contributing to the team effort, e.g. programming, team-leading, writing, editing, graphic design, web development, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Primarily by succeeding in the informal respect economy that operates in these fields.

He or she needs to **impress the people they collaborate** with (especially those who work with them daily or weekly) by some set of

- Playing an active part in a large number of useful side projects and analyses.
- Spotting danger to the physical apparatus coming before things actually break.
- Building, fixing and maintaining parts of the physical apparatus.
- Contributing significant parts of the production software.
- Dealing with difficult parts of the analysis (covariance analysis, systematic uncertainties, finding way to measure irreducible backgrounds, etc).
- Doing a good job of promoting the project, giving talks and interacting with the press.

but most of all

- Taking a leadership role in *planning and organizing* the experimental effort (from conception though feasibility analysis, design, construction, commissioning, calibration, operation through analysis and publication).

Starting at the level of a junior professor dealing with funding becomes a very important part of the mix, as does providing students and post-docs who are themselves good contributors.

---

The flip side is the way you **evaluate candidates** is heavily driven by who you know (it is easier to get a foot in the door if you have worked with someone at the hiring institution), by letters of recommendation and by word of mouth inquires (so gossip plays a part here).